# Styled-components fails to render image

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a problem rendering images through styled-components dynamically.
No errors on the screen and console/ everything set up.
Please check the code and every suggestion will be good! thanks in advance.

Here is the code :

- Styled Hero.js

  ```
  import styled from 'styled-components';

  const StyledHero = styled.header `

      min-height: 60vh
      background-image: url(${props => props.img}) center/
      cover no-repeat;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;

  `

  export default StyledHero;
  ```
- SingleRoom.js

  ```
    return (
        <StyledHero img={images[0]}>
            <Banner title={`${name} room`}>
                <Link to='/rooms' className="btn-primary">
                    back to rooms
                </Link>
            </Banner>
        </StyledHero>
    )
  ```

Comment: What is your path? Are you using an absolute path?

Comment: Yes, I'm using an absolute path.

Comment: background-image -> background ?

Comment: I tried it before.not working